# Delete multiple documents from firebase using cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

[MAIN CATEGORY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smmlo.png)

[SUB CATEGORY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKgZc.png)

[CHAT ROOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDTtS.png)

I am trying to delete multiple firebase documents from cloud function cron job .Function is executing but deletion is not happening .  I have multiple chat rooms , under each chat room there is chat collection . When i call my delete function one by one , it executes properly . But I want to write a cron job that will delete specific chat rooms every month .

To get the list of those specific chat rooms ,  I running multiple firebase loops to get the chatroom document id's .

```
async function deleteAllChatData() {
  admin.firestore()
    .collection(`ENV/${HOST_SERVER_NAME}/MAIN_CATEGORY`)
    .get().then(snapshot => {
      console.log("doc------------snapshot----MAIN_CATEGORY-----", snapshot.size);
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log("doc---------------------", doc.data().isPaid);
        if (doc.data().isPaid) {        // paid vent rooms
          deleteSubCategories(doc.data().id)
        } else {      // free vent rooms
          //clear chatroom chatData
          let chat_id = 'maincategory' + doc.data().id;
          let chatPath = `ENV/${HOST_SERVER_NAME}/CHAT_ROOMS/${chat_id}`;
          deleteCollectionAtPath(chatPath)
        }
      });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("error=====MAIN_CATEGORY======", error);
    })
```

```
async function deleteSubCategories(id) {
  admin.firestore()
    .collection(`ENV/${HOST_SERVER_NAME}/SUB_CATEGORY`)
    .where('parentCategoryId', '==', id)
    .get().then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        if (doc.data().isOpenForChat) {         // sub category chat rooms
          let chat_id = 'subcategory' + createChatId(doc.data().id, doc.data().parentCategoryId);
          let chatPath = `ENV/${HOST_SERVER_NAME}/CHAT_ROOMS/${chat_id}`;
          deleteCollectionAtPath(chatPath)
        } else {        // articles
          deleteArticles(doc.data().id)
        }
      });
    })
}
```

```
async function deleteCollectionAtPath(path) {
  console.log("path=deleteCollectionAtPath===", path);
  firebase_tools.firestore
    .delete(path, {
      project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
      recursive: true,
      yes: true,
      token: functions.config().fb.token
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("SUCCESS----------deleteCollectionAtPath------------");
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("error=====deleteCollectionAtPath======", error);
    })
}
```

When I call deleteCollectionAtPath  separately multiple times , deletion works without any issue , but it wonk work inside the for loop .

I have separate collections  for MAIN_CATEGORY , SUB_CATEGORY , CHAT_ROOMS .  CHAT_ROOM document id is dependant on its parent category .

Can someone pls help how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your Firestore console so we can confirm your db structure.

Comment: @Dharmaraj added the links at the top .

Comment: The code above doesn't handle promises correctly. Each of your functions should return a promise, which should be handled at the caller (or use `async`/`await` appropriately). Otherwise some async tasks will not fully complete, and unhandled promise rejections may result in strange behaviors.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka  can u pls explain using some code . Thanks in advance